# Newpage should start new page numbers with lastpage also

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, lastpage

I want to keep everything in one master file and require to start new page numbers with lastpage also after each `\newpage` command. MWE is below. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

```
\documentclass[12pt,english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1cm,bmargin=1.5cm,lmargin=1cm,rmargin=1cm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{array}

\makeatletter


\usepackage{lastpage} % number of last page 

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\fancyfoot[R]{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
%\fancyfoot[L]{\today}


\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

% Begin Document
\begin{document}


\section{Introduction}

\subsection{Intro1}

% Blind Text
\blindtext[1]

\section{Material \& Method}

% Blind Text
\blindmathpaper


\section{Introduction}

\subsection{Intro1}

% Blind Text
\blindtext[1]

\newpage

\section{Material \& Method}

% Blind Text
\blindmathpaper

\blindtext[1]

\blindmathpaper


% End Document
\end{document}
```

Comment: And what is the problem? Your MWE work fine, page numbering is as expected: from `Page 1  of 5` to `Page 5 of 5`.

Comment: I require `1 of 2` and `2 of 2` before `\newpage` command and then require  `1 of 3`,   `2 of 3` and  `3 of 3`.

Comment: This is not clear from your question ... add your comment to it. `\newpage` even `\clearpage` or`\doubleclearpage` doesn't discontinues numbering. Fro this You need special macro. If you will not receive an answer before, I will write one afternoon (now I'm busy with other tasks).

Comment: `page` is a very unreliable counter so this not that easy!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, I know, a long time ago I design such macro with new counter. Now is my problem to find it :-).

Comment: @Zarko: Clean up your disk from those `tikz` - answers you made :-P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid confusion, I created macros \newgroup to reset the page counter and \thelastpage to print the last page of a "group".  The tricky bit was setting the LastPage label before the end of the page but not changing the counters until after the end of the page (when the header and footer are created).

```
\documentclass[12pt,english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1cm,bmargin=1.5cm,lmargin=1cm,rmargin=1cm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{array}

\newcounter{group}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\newgroup}{%
  \let\@currentlabel=\empty
  \label{LastPage\thegroup}% \pageref doesn't need a \refstepcounter
  \newpage
  \stepcounter{group}%
  \setcounter{page}{1}%
}
\newcommand{\thelastpage}{\@ifundefined{r@LastPage\thegroup}%
  {\pageref{LastPage}}{\pageref{LastPage\thegroup}}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lastpage} % number of last page 

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\fancyfoot[R]{Page \thepage\ of \thelastpage}
%\fancyfoot[L]{\today}


\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

% Begin Document
\begin{document}


\section{Introduction}

\subsection{Intro1}

% Blind Text
\blindtext[1]

\section{Material \& Method}

% Blind Text
\blindmathpaper


\section{Introduction}

\subsection{Intro1}

% Blind Text
\blindtext[1]

\newgroup

\section{Material \& Method}

% Blind Text
\blindmathpaper

\blindtext[1]

\blindmathpaper


% End Document
\end{document}
```